# Xdotool to automate moves in Epiphany (Boulderdash Clone)

Tags: scripts, games, epiphany, xdotool

I'm trying to automate critical moves in my favorite Boulderdash clone called "Epiphany" (available through Ubuntu Software Centre).

In the following example the **character should move: 3x "Down Arrow" and 1x "Right Arrow"**.

[image]

Writing a script is pretty straightforward. Once launched it (1) sets focus to the game window and (2) sends the keystroke commands through Xdotool.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set focus to epiphany
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class epiphany windowactivate
sleep 0.5

# move down one unit
xdotool keydown --delay 100 Down Arrow; xdotool keyup --delay 12 Down Arrow

# move down one unit
xdotool keydown --delay 100 Down Arrow; xdotool keyup --delay 12 Down Arrow

# move down one unit
xdotool keydown --delay 100 Down Arrow; xdotool keyup --delay 12 Down Arrow

# move right one unit
xdotool keydown --delay 100 Right Arrow; xdotool keyup --delay 12 Right Arrow
```

But, this solution doesn't work consistently.

Sometimes the character only completes part of the move - e. g. only 2x "Down Arrow". At other times he moves too slow and is crushed by the diamond.

Are there any suggestions on how to solve this - preferrably using Xdotool?

---

Edit:

The straightforward commands like `xdotool key Down Arrow` - as suggested - don't work.  The character in the game doesn't move at all.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing your delays seems like the obvious answer. The default is 12ms and you've boosted that to 100ms for your arrow presses, without explaining why.

And instead of using `keydown` then `keyup` and having to worry about delays and all that jazz, just use `key`. This allows you to just chain keys together, like a boss:

```
xdotool key Down Down Down Right
```

If you find that's too quick, reintroduce your `--delay` but start from 12 and work up until it works.

Comment: Epiphany doesn't recognize the standard keystrokes sent through `key`. For example `xdotool key Down Arrow` doesn't move the character at all.

Comment: and Reintroducing `--delay` with `key` only delivers movement if very long delays are used around 200 milliseconds.